# what is the difference between oob_decision_function_ and predict function in pulearning?

Tags: python

In the eample of pulearning,

method 1:

```
res = bc.oob_decision_function_[:,1] 
prdict_proba = np.array([i for i in res if not np.isnan(i)])
```

method2 :

```
y_pred_prob = bagging_model.predict_proba(train_x)
```

The result of two method are different, which should i use to predict?
I know the meaning of out of bagging. I do not know  the difference of two method.